# .NET 6 Kestrel HTTP3 and QUIC linux exception This platform doesn't support QUIC or HTTP/3

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, kestrel, amazon-linux, quic

I'm implementing gRPC server using NET 6 C# and try to add QUIC protocol

```
services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(serverOptions =>
{
       serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(900, o =>
       {
           o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;
           o.UseHttps();
      });
            
     serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(890, o =>
     {
           o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http3;
           o.UseHttps();
     });   
});
```

Server deployed on Amazon linux. `sudo yum install -y libmsquic` was started.
But I'm receiving exception as below

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: This platform doesn't support QUIC or HTTP/3.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerImpl.<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
```

Please suggest, what I'm missing?

Comment: HTTP/3 is available in .NET 6 as a preview feature. The HTTP/3 specification isn't finalized and behavioral or performance issues may exist in HTTP/3 with .NET 6. Apps configured to take advantage of HTTP/3 should be designed to also support HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/http3?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft documentation says `NET 6 is only compatible with the 1.9.x versions of libmsquic. Libmsquic 2.x is not compatible due to breaking changes. Libmsquic receives updates to 1.9.x when needed to incorporate security fixes.`

```
sudo yum install -y libmsquic-1.9*
```

Additional using `o.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http3;` Kestrel don't open port. I.e. we need `HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2AndHttp3;`

Comment: You have to add MS packages before you can install libmsquic-1.9*. Link at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software